# Search similar object

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, object, similarity

Assume I have the following array of objects:

```
Object 0:
  [0]=1.1344
  [1]=2.18
  ...
  [N]=1.86
-----------
Object 1 :
  [0]=1.1231
  [1]=2.16781
  ...
  [N]=1.8765
------------- 
Object 2 :
  [0]=1.2311
  [1]=2.14781
  ...
  [N]=1.5465  
--------
Object 17:
  [0]=1.31
  [1]=2.55
  ...
  [N]=0.75
```

How can I compare those objects?

You can see that object 0 and object 1 are very similar but object 17 not like any of them.

I would like to have algorithm tha twill give me all the similar object in my array

Comment: Which programming language you are using?

Comment: @Толя, I use C++

Answer (score 1):

You tag this question with `Algorithm` (and I am not expert in C++) so lets give a pseudo code.

First, you should set a threshold which define 2 var with different under that threshold as similar. Second step will be to loop over all pair of elements and check for similarity.

Consider `A` to be array with `n` objects and `m` to be number of fields in each object.

```
threshold  = 0.1
for i in (0, n):
    for j in (i+1,n):
        flag = true;
        for k in (1,m):
            if (abs(A[i][k] - A[j][k]) > threshold) 
                flag = false // if the absolute value of the diff is above the threshold object are not similar 
                break // no need to continue checks
        if (flag)
            print: element i and j similar // and do what ever
```

Time complexity is `O(m * n^2)`.

Notice that you can use the same algorithm to sort the objects array - declare compare function as the max diff between field and then sort accordingly.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem essentially boils down to nearest neighbor search which is a well researched problem in data mining.

There are diffent approaches to this problem.
I would suggest to decide first what number of similar elements you want OR to set a given threshold for the similarity. Than you have to iterate through all the vectors and compute a distance function between the query vector and each vector in the database.

I would suggest you to use Euclidean distance in your case since you have real nominal data.

You can read more about the topic of nearest neighbor search and Euclidean distance[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a classifier, for your problem there are 2 algorithms depends on what you wanted.

If you need to find which object is most similar to the choosen object-m, you can use nearest neighbor algorithm or else if you need to find similar sets of objects you can use k-means algorithm to find k sets.